# Contact form 7 - Add delay to re-direction after form submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7, dom-events

I want to be able to add a delay to the re-direction that is setup after the successful submission of a form.

Im using this code

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', setTimeout(function( event ) {
    location = 'https://london.tombyrom.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/diploma.pdf';
}, false ), 3000);
</script>
```

But in doing so when you hit the homepage where the form is placed it straight away re-directs you to the PDF. I don’t understand why its re-directing on page load? And not just when wpcf7mailsent event happens?

Website: https://london.tombyrom.co.uk

Sources: https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try the following and see if this works for you?

```
// Onsend contact form 7
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you/';
    }, 2500);

}, false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code,

You can put the code on functions.php file.

```html
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );
 
function redirect_cf7() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you/';
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Hope, it's work!

Comment: There are specific functions in wordpress to enqueue javascript files as well as css files. Including the javascript in functions.php, if it happens to work, is not the right way of doing it.